# Can not ORDER BY an AVG value with certain GROUP BY criteria in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table `data_summaries`. It has such columns as `item_id INT(11)`, `user_grouping TEXT` and `value DECIMAL(10,2)`.

**If I try to make a query that groups the results by `user_grouping` and orders them by the `AVG` of `value`, that fails:**

```
SELECT user_grouping, AVG(value) AS avg_value, SUM(value) AS sum_value
FROM data_summaries
GROUP BY user_grouping
ORDER BY avg_value
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| user_grouping | avg_value | sum_value |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| London        | 50.609733 |  18978.65 |
| Paris         | 50.791733 |  19046.90 |
| New York      | 51.500400 |   2575.02 |
| NULL          | 49.775627 |  18665.86 |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
```

The `ORDER BY` clause does seem to be doing *something* as it does change the order:

```
SELECT user_grouping, AVG(value) AS avg_value, SUM(value) AS sum_value
FROM data_summaries
GROUP BY user_grouping
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| user_grouping | avg_value | sum_value |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| NULL          | 49.775627 |  18665.86 |
| New York      | 51.500400 |   2575.02 |
| London        | 50.609733 |  18978.65 |
| Paris         | 50.791733 |  19046.90 |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
```

On the other hand, ordering by the `SUM` of `value` works as expected:

```
SELECT user_grouping, AVG(value) AS avg_value, SUM(value) AS sum_value
FROM data_summaries
GROUP BY user_grouping
ORDER BY sum_value
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| user_grouping | avg_value | sum_value |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| New York      | 51.500400 |   2575.02 |
| NULL          | 49.775627 |  18665.86 |
| London        | 50.609733 |  18978.65 |
| Paris         | 50.791733 |  19046.90 |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
```

If I group by `item_id` instead, then ordering by the `AVG` works:

```
SELECT item_id, AVG(value) AS avg_value, SUM(value) AS sum_value
FROM data_summaries
GROUP BY item_id
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| item_id | avg_value | sum_value |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|       4 | 49.318225 |  11392.51 |
|       1 | 49.737835 |  11489.44 |
|       2 | 50.420606 |  11647.16 |
|       6 | 51.024242 |  11786.60 |
|       5 | 51.456537 |  11886.46 |
|       3 | 53.213000 |   1064.26 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

How would I need to change the first query to get it ordered by the average?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a MySQL bug, see [Unexpected order for grouped query](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82334), that involves `avg()` in combination with grouping by a `text`-column. It is still open in MySQL 5.7.15.

As a workaround, you can change your datatype to e.g. `varchar`. If you don't need indexes to speed it up, casting should work too:

```
SELECT cast(user_grouping as char(200)), AVG(value) AS avg_value, SUM(value) AS sum_value
FROM data_summaries
GROUP BY cast(user_grouping as char(200))
ORDER BY avg_value
```

*Update:*

The bug is fixed in [MySQL 5.7.17](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-17.html):

> Queries that were grouped on a column of a BLOB-based type, and that were ordered on the result of the AVG(), VAR_POP(), or STDDEV_POP() aggregate function, returned results in the wrong order if InnoDB temporary tables were used. (Bug #22275357, Bug #79366)

Comment: Ah, thank you! No amount of my googling yielded that bug report. The workaround produces the desired results.