# MySQL ORDER BY AVG() DESC not working when certain columns are included

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I'm doing a query to return all the rows in table1, along with their average rating from table2:

```
SELECT `table1`.`description`, AVG( `table2`.`rating` ) AS avg_rating
FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN `table2` ON ( `table2`.`botid` = `table1`.`id` )
GROUP BY `table1`.`id`
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
```

The problem is that even though I specify `DESC`, the results are being returned `ASC`:

```
+-------------+------------+
| description | avg_rating |
+-------------+------------+
| test2       |     1.0000 |
| test3       |     3.0000 |
| test4       |     3.0000 |
| saasdf      |     4.0000 |
+-------------+------------+
```

Why isn't MySQL honoring `ORDER BY...DESC`?

Even weirder, when I remove `table1.description` from the list of columns to retrieve, it works properly:

```
SELECT AVG( `table2`.`rating` ) AS avg_rating
FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN `table2` ON ( `table2`.`botid` = `table1`.`id` )
GROUP BY `table1`.`id`
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
```

Returns:

```
+------------+
| avg_rating |
+------------+
|     4.0000 |
|     3.0000 |
|     3.0000 |
|     1.0000 |
+------------+
```

Here is my data:

table1:

```
id|description
--+-----------
 6|test2
16|test3
54|test4
72|saasdf
```

table2:

```
botid|rating
-----+------
    6|1
   16|3
   54|3
   72|4
```

(For the sake of this example there is a one-to-one relationship between the records in `table1` and `table2`, but in reality there will be a one-to-many relationship.)

And my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `botid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

There are indexes on both `table1.id` and `table2.botid`, although that shouldn't affect the results. I'm using MySQL 5.7.7-rc-log.

I have plenty of experience using aggregate functions, GROUP BY and ORDER BY but I've never come across anything like this. Any suggestions?

Comment: That weird behavior  is because of `longtext` type, If you can change your field type to CHAR/VARCHAR it will run perfectly.

Comment: See my answer here [Can not ORDER BY an AVG value with certain GROUP BY criteria in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719785/can-not-order-by-an-avg-value-with-certain-group-by-criteria-in-mysql/39721880#39721880), there are bugs when you use `AVG` and `(long-)text` (in the question it was `group by` that column, but it's a similar problem). It's fixed in 5.7.17 (using a text-column in a non-group by-context might be fixed earlier.)

Comment: Your use of GROUP BY is **non-standard** although this can be permitted by MySQL depending on server settings. In particular be aware of this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Answer (score 3):

Please upgrade to a GA version (5.7.9 was the first; 5.7.18 exists), then test again.  IIRC, there was a bug somewhere in this area.

If the bug persists, provide the commands to reproduce the error and submit it to bugs.mysql.com .

I strongly recommend you change from MyISAM to InnoDB.  Oracle may throw out the bug report since it involves MyISAM.

Meanwhile, you could see if this gives you the correct ordering:

```
SELECT  `table1`.`description`, 
        ( SELECT  AVG(`rating` )
            FROM  table2
            WHERE  botid = table1.id 
        ) AS avg_rating
    FROM  `table1`
    ORDER BY  avg_rating DESC
```

Provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for both your version and my version.

**Explanation**

Your original query appears to have the "inflate-deflate" problem of `JOIN ... GROUP BY`.  First the `JOIN` gathers more "rows" than you started with, then the `GROUP BY` shrinks it back to the original number.

My rewrite sticks to the original number of rows (in `table1`) and probes table 2 for the necessary stuff.  Primarily (in this situation) it avoids the tmp table and filesort.

Comment: What is the point of using subquery if join is not working.@Rick James please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query

Comment: And the link you provided is a _different_ use case.  So it does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

That weird behavior is because of `longtext`, If you can change your field type to `CHAR/VARCHAR` it will run perfectly.
Or try something like:

`SELECT CAST(table1.desc AS CHAR(128)) AS description, AVG( table2.rating ) AS avg_rating
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON ( table2.botid = table1.id )
GROUP BY table1.id
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC;`

Comment: That seems to work, but I'm wondering if this a bug or a feature in MySQL? It sure seems like a bug to me because I can't imagine any reason why the data type of a column I'm not ordering by should affect the ordering of another column.

Comment: Yes, it is a MySql bug which got fixed in 5.7.17 release,   
Check: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-17.html

Answer (score 0):

Working as expected for when run on maria db.Please check your query once because your order by is working on **description** column  instead of avg_rating.
[image]

You can also try

```
SELECT `table1`.`description`, AVG( `table2`.`rating` ) AS avg_rating FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN `table2` ON ( `table2`.`botid` = `table1`.`id` ) GROUP BY `table1`.`id` ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

and check the output again.will it remain the same?

Comment: As has been pointed out by two other people, it was caused by a bug in my version of MySQL that has since been fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one

SELECT *, AVG( table2.rating ) AS avg_rating  FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.botid GROUP BY table1.id ORDER BY table2.rating

give me. feedback

Comment: Read. About. GROUP BY

Comment: This doesn't select the average. How is this supposed to solve my problem?

Comment: SELECT *,AVG( `table2`.`rating` ) AS avg_rating FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.botid GROUP BY table1.id ORDER BY table2.rating

Comment: @JorhendzStudios, that query does not do what I want. I want to order by AVG( table2.rating ).